# regarding the broadcast error for putting one array into a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I defined a two-dimensional array as follows:

```
predict_result = np.zeros((69,1000))
```

In the loop, I was trying to inject a predicted one-dimensional array into it.

```
for ij in range(0,1000):
    # # some code to generate Ypredict
    predict_result[:,ij]=Ypredict
```

`Ypredict` is always the shape of `(69,1)`.  However, running the program gives the following error

> predict_result[:,ij]=Ypredict ValueError: could not broadcast input
>   array from shape (69,1) into shape (69)

How can I correct this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either change the (69,1) array to (69,), or make the receiving slot (69,1)

`ravel` is one on several ways of flattening the 2d array:

```
predict_result[:,ij]=Ypredict.ravel()
```

Index with a list rather than a scalar works the other way:

```
predict_result[:,[ij]]=Ypredict
```

You could also use broadcasting to put the smaller array into the larger without a loop - as noted in the other answer:

```
(69,1000) <= (69,1)  works
```

The 2 basic rules of broadcasting:

- a size 1 dimension can be added at the start to match the number of dimensions
- all size 1 dimensions can be changed to match to same dimension of the other array(s).

(69,) cannot be changed to match (69,1).  But (69,1) can be changed to match (69,1000).

Answer (score -2):

You don't need for-loop:

```
predict_result[:] = Ypredict
```

Or you can create the result by `repeat`:

```
np.repeat(Ypredict, 1000, axis=1)
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood what "some code to generate represents"